# C++ program exiting without error. How to debug?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I have a program (full code [here](https://github.com/gbleaney/Allocator-Benchmarks/blob/master/benchmarks/allocators/growth.cc)) that is exiting around the 46000th iteration:

```
{
    PROCESSER<MONO_CONT> processer;
    c_start = std::clock();
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocatoralloc(pool, sizeof(pool));
        MONO_CONT* container = new(alloc) MONO_CONT(&alloc);
        container->reserve(elements);
        processer(container, elements);
    }
    c_end = std::clock();
    std::cout << (c_end - c_start) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ";
}
```

In this case, `MONO_CONT` is a `vector<string, scoped_allocator_adaptor<alloc_adaptor<BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator>>>`. 
My understanding is that the `scoped_allocator_adaptor` would make sure that the supplied allocator would be used for allocations for the strings being passed in, thus ensuring the strings would be deallocated at the end of each loop iteration (avoiding @1201ProgramAlarm's suggestion for the problem). The `alloc_adapter` is just a wrapper to make Bloomberg allocators conform to the proper interface.

`PROCESSER` is the following templated functor that just performs some basic operations on the templated container, `MONO_CONT`:

```
template<typename DS2>
struct process_DS2 {
    void operator() (DS2 *ds2, size_t elements) {
        escape(ds2);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
            ds2->emplace_back(&random_data[random_positions[i]], random_lengths[i]);
        }
        clobber();
    }
};
```

Note that `escape` and `clobber` are just some magic that do nothing other than defeat the optimizer (see [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) if you're interested). `random_data` is just an array of `char`s containing garbage. `random_positions` defines valid indices into `random_data`. `random_lengths` defines a valid string length (does not go off the end of the garbage data) starting from the corresponding position in `random_positions`.

I have similar code that runs the exact same number of iterations, and does not fail:

```
{
    PROCESSER<MONO_CONT> processer;
    c_start = std::clock();
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator alloc(pool, sizeof(pool));
        MONO_CONT container(&alloc);
        container.reserve(elements);
        processer(&container, elements);
    }
    c_end = std::clock();
    std::cout << (c_end - c_start) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ";
}
```

The main difference between the two snippets is that in the first, I'm `new`ing the container into the allocator, and then passing the allocator to the container, relying on on the allocator's destruction to deallocate all the memory of the container (without having to actually call the destructor of the container itself). In the second snippet I'm allowing the more natural destruction of the container by going out of scope at the end of each iteration of the loop.

I'm building this with Clang, running in a Docker container on Debian. An suggestions on what the issue could be or how I could start debugging this?

Comment: The first example uses `placement-new`.  So where is the explicit call to the destructor?  https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As far as I know it's defined to not call the destructor, given that the destructor of the allocator cleans up the memory, and I never access the container after it's memory is disposed of. Take a look at the last 3 paragraphs of Chapter 3 for more details on why I'm doing this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0089r0.pdf

Comment: If you're concerned about allocator efficiency, consider creating the `MONO_CONT` object outside the loop, `clear()`ing it after each iteration, then the `reserve()`s reach a high water mark and rarely need any allocation done.

Comment: @TonyD, normally that would be a great suggestion, but in this case, I'm actually benchmarking allocator performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're relying on the allocator's destruction to deallocate the memory allocated for `container`, this will not free up memory used by the contained `string`s, which will not be using the allocator for the `vector` but will be using the global heap (`new`).  When the program runs out of memory it exits without reporting anything, possibly because it doesn't have enough memory available to do so.

In your second version `container` is destroyed which will free up the allocated strings when the `vector` is destroyed.

As far as how to debug something like this, the usual advice of "try stepping thru it in the debugger" is a start.  If you run attached in a debugger it might break when the `std::bad_alloc` exception is created or thrown.  And you can monitor the process's memory usage.

Comment: I added some additional exposition to my post explaining my use of `scoped_allocator_adaptor`, which I think should have me covered here

Comment: After some additional digging, it appears that you may be right. I forgot to template the string to accept the custom allocator from the `scoped_allocator_adaptor`, so it was instead going to the heap